# Bootstrap data-toggle="buttons" radio checked property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, onchange

I see that the Bootstrap radio buttons (created with data-toggle="buttons") **change** event switches the **active** class between the labels and does no effect on the **checked** properties of the real radio buttons. Is that a normal behaviour or do I have a mistake?

Or, how can I bind this **active** class of label and **checked** property of the radio each other **in two-way** so that they change at the same time?

Example Code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this issue was fixed?. Because me also having same issues..

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options3" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Regards

Comment: Having the `name` attributes not sharing the same name break radio button group's toggle behavior.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: even the original docs you're copying from (either [3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) or [4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)) are both having `name="options"`!

Answer (score -1):

If you’re pre-toggling a button, you must manually add the `.active` class and `aria-pressed="true"` to the .

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#toggle-states